# Looking for PHP/MySQL-based ad manager

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, advertising, mysql

Could you recommend based on your experience a PHP/MySQL-based admin interface for managing your website ads? In order to be really useful, such application should have:

-**basic CRM functionality** to track who is providing the ads

-**multilingual multi country support**: have the ability to specify for the same ad, different versions for multiple  languages/countries

-**predefined ad formats** (google Ads, flash ads...) **and [sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_banner)** with corresponding PHP helpers so as to insert in the HTML code the necessary markup to properly integrate the ad.

Ideally if that application could be desgined for Zend Framework that would be awesome (but I think I'm dreaming at this point).

Comment: I'm thinking this might be too localized.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The definition of Too Localized is, "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." When a user is looking for a software with very specific needs it tends to become too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one of any consequence that I could recommend is the [Open X Ad Platform](http://www.openx.com/publisher/compare-ad-server-products). They have a downloadable free version that you host yourself.

It is extensible with plugins and has some pretty advanced delivery options.

One warning that I will give you is that, at this point, the product is basically unsupported. They focus all of their attention on the paid, hosted version, so you are pretty much on your own.

That being said, I have used it for two years now, serving a couple million ads a month and haven't run into an issue we couldn't fix.